# Workbook_SheetChange in Personal.xlsb not working in other workbooks unless I trigger the event in Personal first

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following VBA code in my Personal.xlsb file stored in "ThisWorkbook":

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)    
Application.Caption = "Saved"    
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Source As Range)    
Application.Caption = "Not Saved"    
End Sub
```

This code works fine in the Personal.xlsb file - the code changes the name of the file at the top of the screen in Excel when ever I make a change to the Excel file or save it, I get the desired results at the top of screen with the title change of either `Not Saved` or `Saved`.

If I open another excel file the code does not work for the `Workbook_Sheetchange` code, unless I make a change in the Personal file first.  The `workbook_AfterSave` works, but not the `Workbook_SheetChange` code in this scenario.

The only way it works is if I make a change in the Personal file first, then it works in the other open workbooks.

So, to clarify If I just open a new workbook (with the Personal hidden in the background and no changes made to the Personal file) the `Workbook_SheetChange` does not work.  I have to first make a change in the personal file, then the `Workbook_Sheetchange` code works in the other open workbooks..... can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
Dim WithEvents app As Application
Dim WithEvents awb As Workbook

Private Sub ShowState()
    On Error Resume Next
    Set app = Application
    Set awb = ActiveWorkbook
    app.Caption = IIf(ActiveWorkbook.Saved, "Saved", "Not Saved")
End Sub

Private Sub awb_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    ShowState
End Sub

Private Sub awb_Open()
    ShowState
End Sub

Private Sub awb_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    ShowState
End Sub

Private Sub awb_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    ShowState
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ShowState
End Sub

Private Sub app_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    ShowState
End Sub

Private Sub app_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    ShowState
End Sub

Private Sub app_WorkbookAfterSave(ByVal Wb As Workbook, ByVal Success As Boolean)
    ShowState
End Sub

Private Sub app_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    ShowState
End Sub
```

Comment: Mo Khalefa - Thanks for the Code - it works as long as I keep the Personal.xlsb file open, but as soon as I hide the file in excel (under View menu) the code does not work on the other workbooks.  Is there a setting I need to make to so this is available when the Personal file is hidden.  I do not want to see the Personal file when i open excel and just have it in the background.

Comment: @SSchwan - I edit my post ,now it works even if you start it hidden

Comment: @SSchwan - You can also try to make it as `Excel Add-Ins` after that there is no need to open Personal.xlsb file anymore

Comment: Mo Khalefa - I saved this as an Add-in and works well.  However, when you open an excel sheet, it says "Excel" which is good - this indicates no changes have been made.  Then when you make a change or save the file, it gives you the Not Saved or Saved status which is what I want.  What I did notice, is when you open a 2nd workbook using the New icon in excel after a change is made in the first workbook, it gives a status of "Not Saved" instead of Excel in the 2nd Workbook when opened.  Is there a way for the Status to always say "Excel" when a WB us first opened but no changes have occurred?

Comment: @SSchwan - Ok this is how it works ,save the code as `*.xlam` > close all instances > open new instance of excel > `Add-Ins` tab > `Add-Ins` > Browse `*.xlam` > then this add ins will be available until you deactivate it or change its path

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture events regardless of the workbook (ie. for any workbook open in a given Excel instance) then you need "Application events" - see http://cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx for example.

You can still set this up in your Personal.xlsb: in the `ThisWorkbook` code module you can do this if you want (eg) to trap the selection change event across all workbooks:

[image]

If you select "app" on the left-hand drop-down at the top of the module you can select the application event you want to handle from the right-hand drop-down.